# TFS query on HTML-field for empty value

Tags: tfs-2015

I want to get with a wiql query all workitem that have an empty HTML field.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

To query out those work items who have empty HTML field like Description, using the query from TFS web page couldn't do that. There's no operator like "isEmpty or isNotEmpty" to use. Here is [a uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3080939-introduce-is-empty-operator-in-tfs-wiql-for-rich) about your request, and according to it, this feature is under review now.

As a workaround, you could use Excel to filter those work items. Write a simple query and [export those work items to Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel). Then use the filter In Excel.

You could also use TFS object model api to get those empty field workitems, here is an example:

```
        WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
        string queryString = "Select [State], [Title],[Description] From WorkItems Where [Work Item Type] = 'User Story' and [System.TeamProject] = 'TeamProjectName'";

        // Create and run the query.
        Query query = new Query(workItemStore, queryString);
        WorkItemCollection witCollection = query.RunQuery();

        foreach (WorkItem workItem in witCollection)
        {
            //check if the field is empty
            if(workItem.Fields["Description"].Value.ToString() == string.Empty || workItem.Fields["Description"].Value.ToString() == "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(workItem.Title);
            }
     }
```

Comment: In TFS 2018 it is still not possible. Maybe in the future Azure DevOps